# Windows Communication Foundation передача классов

Tags: c#, классы, wcf, клиент, хост

Есть некоторое WCF приложение. В контракте на хосте WCF есть такой метод:

```
public void InsertCar(ingentory car)
        {               
            InsertCar(car.ID, car.Make, car.Color, car.PetNama);
        }
```

Как видим, метод принимает не стандартный тип данных. Следовательно для работы клиента с этим типом я реализую класс с помощью атрибутов [DataContract] и [DataMember]:

```
 [DataContract] public class ingentory
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int? ID;
        [DataMember]
        public string Make;
        [DataMember]
        public string Color;
        [DataMember]
        public string PetNama;
    }
```

И вот тут у меня возникает вопрос. Как с клиента на хост передавать класс `ingentory`. Я так понял, что в клиенте тоже нужно реализовать класс `ingentory` и просто его передать, а WCF уже сам разберется что и куда пихать?

P.S. Не очень разобрался в WCF. Буду благодарен - если исправите меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобрался. После того как в клиентском приложении мы добавим ссылку на службу. У нас появится пространство имен, в котором будет класс `ingentory` и мы сможем использовать его в коде клиента. Например как то так:

```
foreach (ServiceReference1.ingentory test in client.GetInventory())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test.ID); 
            }
```